# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. While installing aspose-total-java

Tags: python, pip, aspose-cells, aspose-slides

```
Collecting aspose-total-java
  Using cached aspose-total-java-22.6.0.tar.gz (3.4 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zqnlm7yk\aspose-total-java_a857f3e3c09849118cf54d8475471634\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

I try to install aspose-total-java on windows and even updated setup tools and pip version still I'm getting this message:

Comment: We found the issue you have mentioned while installing Aspose.Total for Python via Java package from pip using command line. Our concerned team is already working over it to figure it out. In the meantime, please download/install individual Python APIs (e.g., Aspose.PDF for Python via Java,  Aspose.Cells for Python via Java, Aspose.BarCode for Python via Java, Aspose.Diagram for Python via Java) separately from respective download modules (https://releases.aspose.com/).

Comment: We have fixed the issue and pushed the changes. Please try installing Aspose.Total for Python via Java package again from pip (https://pypi.org/project/aspose-total-java/#files).